# Error report from unpublished version -- have I been hacked?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an UncaughtExceptionHandler in my Android code.  In the event of an uncaught exception, my app sends version info, device characteristics, and a stack trace via HTTP POST to my server.  (My posted privacy policy makes this clear.)  The server also logs the IP address of where the error report comes from.

Last night I got a notification of an uncaught exception.  It was from a version number of my app that has not been published.  The implications are staggering.  I'm hoping there's an innocent explanation I have overlooked.

Yesterday evening I incremented the version number to 254 on my AndroidManifest.xml.  I made some mods to my code, and I tested them, using Android Studio and a USB connection, on 4 different phones and tablets of varying Android versions.  I wrapped everything up a few minutes before midnight EST, and turned off the computer.

The error report was sent at 12:10 am EST this morning.  The IP address it came from is registered to Amazon Technologies in Seattle, WA.  (I'm in Pennsylvania.)  The version number of the app was 254.  The software was running on "Model AOSP on ARM Emulator".  The error came from the onClick callback of an "Upgrade" button on a dialog fragment that may have been displayed.  I wasn't working on that part of the code last night.

There are several versions of my code in the Google Play store, and a few more that I've posted on my website for tester to try.  But version 254 was created last night, and was never sent to Google nor anywhere else.  There are other indications that make it unlikely the report could have come from earlier versions.

The stack trace was unobfuscated.  All published versions should have obfuscated code.

I never use emulators.  I much prefer to debug on actual hardware.

An innocent explanation might be that I inadvertently generated the error message myself.  I would have had to fire up an emulator, bring up the dialog fragment and click "Upgrade".  That still wouldn't explain the Amazon IP address.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: I think you need to move the question to https://security.stackexchange.com/